# Need help to approve Facebook business_management and catalog_management permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need catalog_management and business_management app permissions. I will use these permissions to manage business and catalog through my application. But I have no idea about Facebook's approval requirements especially for these two services.

Please help if somebody already knows the process for business_management and catalog_management
permissions approval

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look your application "App Review".
You can find more details below video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2Z0segBrNk